# Using Akka IndirectActorProducer and serializable Props

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, akka, guice, akka-actor

I want to use Guice Dependency Injection with Akka Actors.

Akka documentation, [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#dependency-injection), suggests to use `IndirectActorProducer` for dependency injection.
But it is not explained, or I don't understand, the reason.

In my opinion it should be used to avoid passing not serializable components/services inside Props. But other examples that I have found ([here](https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice) or [here](https://medium.com/supercharges-mobile-product-guide/akka-with-google-guice-adb2b83f045)) pass the whole `Injector` class that I'm quite sure it is not serializable.

So my questions are:

1. How and why `IndirectActorProducer` should be used?
2. `Props` must be serializable? It is fine to pass Guice `Injector` as a Props parameters?

I known that there are similar questions, but in my opinion there isn't a clear answer yet:

- [Injecting services into Scala Akka Actors with Google Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755016/injecting-services-into-scala-akka-actors-with-google-guice)
- [Dependency injection with Akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875368/dependency-injection-with-akka)
- [How to make guice injection work with Akka 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116356/how-to-make-guice-injection-work-with-akka-2-5)

Comment: Why Guice? It removes type safety and I cannot imagine it works reliably when you add sth like Akka Cluster. In Scala people in general move away from runtime reflection and favor of compile time reflection or no reflection and just types. Is there some strong reason for using reflection based DI?

Comment: @mateusz-kubuszok Main reason is because we already use Guice for other projects, with both Java and Scala, so I prefer to have a similar architecture. And I like Guice, very easy to use. But I'm interested in other approaches. What do you suggest? I heard about the cake pattern... Can you point me to some example for Akka actors? Thanks!

Comment: This can be useful: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/akka-actor-dependency-injection-and-indirectactorproducer/4040

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the answer you are looking for so keep the question open in case someone else provide more Guice-bases answer.

Basically the reason we use DI frameworks/libraries is because of overhead of passing arguments manually and maybe also interface-implementation decoupling (though the later can be simply solved by passing down functions in constructors and using them to create the implementation, so it is not that much of an argument).

In Scala, at least in codebases that goes away from Java for simpler projects people just pass down things as arguments:

```
class MyActor(name: String, surname: String) extends Actor { ... }

def createActor(name: String, surname: String) =
   system.actorOf(Props(MyActor.class, name, surname))
```

People, who don't like to do things manually, have some other options, but most of them are based on compile time reflection like e.g. [Macwire](https://di-in-scala.github.io/#akka) which uses types to inject things:

```
// tags used to distinguish things - something like named instance in Guice
// but on types instead of strings
sealed trait Name
sealed trait Name
class MyActor(name: String @@ Name,
              surname: String @@ Surname) extends Actor { ... }

def createActor(name: String @@ Name, surname: String @@ Surname) =
   // wire is a macro that puts arguments into constructor by looking at
   // variables in the current scope and their types
   system.actorOf(Props(wire[MyActor]))
```

Since here linking errors appear at compile time and not during runtime, a lot of people consider this easier to maintain than solutions proposed by Java ecosystem.

And because this macro just unrolls to plain old argument passing code as long as your arguments are serializable you have no issues like unserializable `Injector`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But the problem with Props not serializable I think is the same. Let's say that you need to pass a database connection, or any other not serializable service. From my understanding `IndirectActorProducer` should be used in this case. And can be used with both Guice or Macwire. Do you agree?